# How do i implement draglistener without having to touch and hold before dragging the view

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple anagram game using android studio and I want the user to rearrange the words using drag and drop in a recyclerview or listView in android. But i don't want the user to touch and hold before being able to drag the view, i want the view to be draggable instantly the user touches it.
please any help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a free code writing service and you are required to show us either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you've made. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question, which will lead to more users being willing to help you with your problem!

Comment: I will still try to help you, but please consider my first comment for the future. First off, are you sure you want to use DragListener? It seems to be a very weird interface that merely implements methods of Mouse- and MouseMotion-Listener. Reading the API of the two mouse listeners, it seems that ```mouseDragged()``` does exactly what you want. Maybe consider [this code example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/a-simple-mouse-drag-example/) which has a working MouseMotionListener that drags on click and doesn't wait for hold. Hope I could help, otherwise let me know!

Comment: call beginDrag() immediately in onTouch()